# How do I keep thermal labels from fading?

Tags: paper, labeling

I'm using thermal labels as contact information and descriptions on the backs of wood products that I sell. I was thinking, that if I could cover the label, with a clear permanent coating, that it may be legible for several years. For instance, a thermal label on wood, covered with shellac, epoxy or clear spray paint.....
Has anyone ever tried anything like this? If so, does it work?

Comment: What do you mean by thermal label?  A label printed on thermal paper?

Comment: IMO it is light that fades thermal printing fastest, especially direct sunlight, and it fades when kept away from light too. It isn't very durable, end of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent a receipt from fading?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/how-can-i-prevent-a-receipt-from-fading)

Comment: Hi JEllis, Welcome to Lifehacks. Don't forget to visit the [Tour] and [Help] to find out more about this site and how it works to get the most from your visits here. Your question is similar to this one: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/how-can-i-prevent-a-receipt-from-fading/21440#21440

Answer (score 4):

**Paper Label HACK**: Have you considered using an electric (or manual) **Branding Iron** for your wood products?

[image: branded image on wood]

For use on wood or leather, electric branding irons have solid brass heads that can be set with up to 20 characters per line (including spaces and punctuation).

These irons reach over 720°F (382°C) after about 15 minutes. One supplier (search online) offers one model with “HANDCRAFTED BY” as the first line, another with “FABRIQUÉ PAR” as the first line, and **a custom model with two lines of your choice**. Letters are upper case, 3/16" high. For names such as “MACDONALD”, the “A” and “C” will be upper case, but in a reduced size.

[image: Branding Iron]

Looks great. Fits your product line appropriately.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Thermal images fade. They are not archival. Treating them for permanence is an exercise in futility.

Rather than all that ridiculous amount of effort to save a thermal image, my HACK is to make a photocopy (with carbon-based toner) that does not fade.

Better, make the original image using a black/white laser printer so that you have a choice of stable base material to print on. Your choices are paper, card-stock, and plastic. In addition, some materials have adhesive-backing for peel-stick application.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an engraving pen (rotary abrasive kind) and just write your name in for now. You can perhaps create hardwood plinths later that you will 3D router, or look at a low-powered laser engraver that will burn some wording into the wood; it's much more permanent.

If you're after something lifehacky you might find some success with a number and letter punch set (or even bending a design out of metal wire), heating it up and burning a design in by resting wood on the hot object...

Answer (score 0):

Photography developing has several bathes for prints and one is the fixer bath
which stops the chemical process and washes out some of the developer.
Freezing the chemical reaction permanently.
Stopping Thermal Print reaction on paper coating of Receipt paper could be done with a chemical pen of some sort, however I have not found anything in my search on the Internet. I need some chemistry background to DIY..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).